# How to implement a nuxt project in ssg mode

Tags: nuxt3

I have created a Nuxt project it's a blog platform. but when I want to implement it in SSG mode, I get errors while prerendering. First I receive an error saying
FAILED TO PARSE URL FROM ADMINPANEL.
And I get the same error from 2 more pages.
and then I get to prerendering section and it shows some numbers in ms and pages names.
And at the end it says:
EXITING DUE TO PRERENDER ERRORS.

I just want to generate it in ssg mode